# Run convert from ImageMagick script file

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to stitch (thousands) of images together via coordinate system using ImageMagick. Because the command is so long, I can't pass it via CLI, but have to save it to a script to load later.

The script looks like this:

`script.txt`

```
convert
( foo.png -repage +0+0 )
( bar.png -repage +0+37 )
-layers merge
out.png
```

I then run `magick.exe -script script.txt`

But get the following error:

```
magick.exe: unable to open image 'convert': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3457.
magick.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/512.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The -script command is for ImageMagick 7. You must explicitly -write the output in the script command. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/bugs/IMv7_Scripting.txt

For example, here is a simple script file that I call testscript

```
#!/path/to/magick -script
rose: -scale 200% -write big_rose.png
```

To run it you simple use:

```
magick -script testscript
```

So for your command, try the script as

```
#!/path/to/magick -script
( foo.png -repage +0+0 ) ( bar.png -repage +0+37 ) -layers merge -write out.png
```

(Note I have written it as one line. If you want to use multiple lines, then you must use Windows line ending character, ^, at the end of each line to show continuation to the next line)

Then call it as

```
magick -script yourscript
```