# imageMagick: hexagonal tiling of many different images (having the same size)

Tags: imagemagick, offset, tile

I have many different PNG images all with the same size (142x163). These are badges for students. You can see three examples below, but there are more of them. I would like to create a single large image where all individual badges are arranged in a hexagonal grid to maximize the printed area. I just need to leave a little space between them to cut them out safely.

I'm wondering what the best way is to go about this.

I have a list of how many badges of each kind I need to print, and I can write code to specify the position (offset) of each individual badge in the hexagonal grid. However, I'm not sure about the correct way to feed this information into a script for ImageMagick to execute.

I guess I need something like: create an image placing `badge1.png` at position 1, `badge2.png` at position 2, `badge3.png` at position 3, `badge3.png` at position 4, and so on. This could go on for a bit, with 50 to 100 badges (I'm thinking of filling an A3 sheet with `3cm x 3cm` badges).

What would the correct syntax be? Would ImageMagick handle this?

Thanks a lot for any insight.

Francesco

```
[![badge1][1]][1]
[![badge2][2]][2]
[![badge3][3]][3]
```

[image: badge1]
[image: badge2]
[image: badge3]

EDIT: as required, I'm attaching the script I'm currently using:

```
magick -background none \
\( ph4campoBstatico.png ph5EqMaxOndeEM.png MMprodVett.png ph4UeV_elettrici.png +smush 8 +repage -set page +0+0 \) \
\( MMsimboli.png ph3dinamicaSNI.png ph1prefissi.png ph1calibroVentesimale.png +smush 8 +repage -set page +76+130 \) \
-layers merge +repage \
-background white -flatten \
result.png
```

This command works, but it converts an entire "row" to grayscale whenever the first image is grayscale (see output below).

Since the number of files involved is much larger than 8, I tried to write this command in a file "script" and run it as `magick -script script`. What I find is that I have to prepend `-write` to the filename. Also, it seems to me that the backslashes at the end of each line are unimportant in the file.

The output of the command is

[image: result.png]

Only the first image in the second row should be black and white. The others should be in color. Colors are "removed" from a row only when the first image is grayscale.

Comment: Cannot see your images.  Consider appending images for every other row and offset each alternate row.  See for example my bash unix script, tileimage at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php

Comment: sorry, the IA's suggestions messed with the images I included. I think I was able to display them. For some reason I cannot delete the code snipped the AI introduced. Thanks for your suggestion, I'll definitely look into your script.

Comment: IMHO you are perhaps optimizing the print (by 25%)  but you are making the cutting a lot more difficult since you won't have a single cut across the whole sheet.

Comment: @xenoid yes, I see what you mean, but it is more a matter of cost. I need to print the badges on heat transfer paper. The print shop charges 20€ per sheet :). Also,  laying the badges out onto a hexagonal lattice looks cool for other purposes too.

Comment: @fmw42 I looked into your script. It seems to me that it would be perfect for tiling one single badge, repeating it many times. If I had unlimited resources I could surely print one sheet per badge.  However, I'd like to print only the badges I need, which means that each tile can be different from the previous ones, in principle. I do not seem to find a code snippet for that purpose in your script.

Comment: -write filename.suffix is needed when using -script. That is just the way it works. But you should remove the output file in the script. Backslashes are only needed when you want to make the command multiple lines when very long so that it is more readable.  Add -colorspace sRGB to the end of the code lines for each row of images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding -colorspace sRGB or -type truecolor after reading the images in Imagemagick. Also prepend PNG24: to the output filename if the previous does not work by itself but only for PNG output.

```
magick -background none \
\( ph4campoBstatico.png ph5EqMaxOndeEM.png MMprodVett.png ph4UeV_elettrici.png -colorspace sRGB +smush 8 +repage -set page +0+0 \) \
\( MMsimboli.png ph3dinamicaSNI.png ph1prefissi.png ph1calibroVentesimale.png -colorspace sRGB +smush 8 +repage -set page +76+130 \) \
-layers merge +repage \
-background white -flatten \
PNG24:result.png
```

Comment: great! Works like a charm! I upvoted all the replies I received, because each one contained very useful tips. I guess this last reply is the one best solving my original problem, so I'm choosing this one.
Oh, I discovered that my school owns a Silhouette Cutter. I'm wondering whether it's possible to hardcode the cutting instructions in the image, rather than using "Silhouette Studio". But this is a matter for a different question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternate way to do that in Imagemagick. Use smush X to create each row. Smush X is like append with an offset.  Then use one -page +X+Y to set the spacing between the two rows. And finally use -layers merge to combine according to the -page offsets. Then flatten over the desired background color or leave as transparent background.

```
magick -background none \
\( img1.png img2.png img3.png +smush 4 +repage \) \
\( img3.png img1.png img2.png +smush 4 +repage -set page +72+126 \) \
-layers merge +repage \
-background white -flatten \
result.png
```

[image]

```
magick -background none \
\( img1.png img2.png img3.png +smush 4 +repage \) \
\( img3.png img1.png +smush 4 -set page +72+126 \) \
-layers merge +repage \
-background white -flatten \
result2.png
```

[image]

Comment: this is also pretty interesting. With this solution I wouldn't need to create multiple copies of "repeated" badges, but rather a script listing all the badges I want to include in the print. I wonder which one is the better choice.
Perhaps this one, because it saves memory? I guess that in the end imagemagick should manage the same number of images, but with GeeMack's solution I would need to explicitly create them, whereas with fmw42's repeating the image name should be enough...

Comment: You can use -duplicate in place of repeating the image name. That way you are not reading the same image multiple times.

Comment: you mean in your approach, right? That's definitely interesting, thanks again. Come to think about it, I have a list of badges for each student. If I lay the badges out as they come from the list, I can cut out the whole badge group for each student, and let them have fun cutting their individual badges, if they need to. Otherwise, they get them in a nice honeycomb pattern, after all!

Comment: I'm having a couple of problems with the script: 1) I am not getting any output unless I add a ```-write ``` option just before ```result.png```. Is that a mac thing? Also, the badges I attached as examples are black and white, but many others are in color. However, sometimes they turn into grayscale. I did some experimenting with the number of rows/columns, and I am almost certain that this happens whenever the first badge in a row is black and white or grayscale. I'd post examples, but I do not know how to do that in a comment. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Imagemagick makes the output the same color as the first image in the command line unless you add -colorspace sRGB before the output or if PNG preface the output name with PNG24:outname.png. I would have to see your command line to fix your issue with the final -write. That should not be necessary if the command is written correctly.  Post your troublesome command. Be sure that all `\\` do not have spaces after them.

Comment: the script is 
```-background none \
-define colorspace:auto-grayscale=false \
\( ph4campoBstatico.png ph5EqMaxOndeEM.png MMprodVett.png ph4UeV_elettrici.png +smush 8 +repage -set page +0+0 \) \
\( MMsimboli.png ph3dinamicaSNI.png ph1prefissi.png ph1calibroVentesimale.png +smush 8 +repage -set page +76+130 \) \
-layers merge +repage \
-background white -flatten \
result.png
``` 
Sorry, I'm unable to add newlines in the above code. If I run this, I get the following error ```magick: unable to open image 'result.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3569.``` .

Comment: in the above case (which I run as ```magick -script script```) adding ```-write``` just before the filename eliminates the error and produces an output. However, all the images in the second row turn out to be grayscale, although only the first one in the row (MMsimboli.png) is. Also, the very first image, ph4campoBstatico.png, is in color, and does not get changed to grayscale in result.png. Finally, using ```PNG24:result.png``` does not cure the problem. It seems to be a problem "inside a single row".

Comment: Magick scripts do not write an output. So you must add the -write at the end to get your output. That is just the way they work.  Please post your script in your original question where it can be formatted properly so that the end of line markers are at the end of lines.  First test your command line before making it into a script. Then make it into a script and remove the result.png. The put your result.png as -write result.png for the script only

Comment: I added the script to the original post. It works without ```-write``` but still produces an unwanted conversion to grayscale whenever the first image in a row is grayscale. I tried several things in the script, like ```PNG24:result.png``` or ```-define colorspace:auto-grayscale=false``` to no avail. 
Converting the images causing the problem with ```convert MMsimboli.png -define png:color-type=2 MMsimboli.png``` gives the desired result. 
I'm looking up a way of achieving that in the script, without explicitly converting all the images.

Answer (score 3):

Given a number of images with the same dimensions, named "tile-*.png", and with transparent backgrounds, you can use ImageMagick v7 to arrange them into a hexagon-oriented grid with a Windows command like the one below...

First, this command draws a hexagon on a 200x200 tile, duplicates it to make several more, 35 in this example, to simulate a bunch of tiles to arrange...

```
magick -size 200x200 -background none -fill none ^
   -strokewidth 4 -stroke black xc:none ^
   -draw "polygon 22,54 100,10 178,54 178,146 100,190 22,146" ^
   -duplicate 34 tile-%02d.png
```

[image]

This next command will read in all the tiles created by the above command, and arrange them into a grid of a specified number of units wide...

```
set COLS=5

magick tile-*.png ^
   -background none ^
   -gravity center ^
   -extent %[h]x%[h] ^
   +gravity ^
   +append ^
   +repage ^
   -crop %[fx:%COLS%*h]x%[h] ^
   -splice %[fx:(t%2)*h/2]x0 ^
   -set page +0+%[fx:t*h*0.866] ^
   -layers merge ^
      result.png
```

That sets the number of columns you want as a Windows variable %COLS%.

Then the ImageMagick command reads in all the images named "tile-*.png" and makes sure they're centered in square tiles.

It appends them all horizontally, crops that into the number of rows required to make the grid, and adjusts the spacing on the ends of the rows.

Next it sets the page geometry on all these horizontal strips of images, in essence moving each one "h*0.866" farther down the page than the previous.

With all the geometry set, the "-layers merge" operation flattens them into the finished grid.

[image]

Edisted to add: I'm not able to translate this into a *nix command right now, but converting the carets "^" to backslashes "\" and fixing the syntax on that shell variable should get you most of the way.

Comment: this is awesome, thanks! I tried it out (with fmw42's adaptations) and of course it works. I only had to change the size of the image, because my badges are rectangular, their height being larger than their width. Changing %w into %h was enough. In my case, this method involves creating multiple copies of some badges, but that's no big deal.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Yep. I had an error in my example. The "-extent" should be HxH instead of WxW. I edited my example to correct it.

Comment: If your badge images are all the same dimensions, and the quantity you want to use for a single sheet are all in one folder, you can read in "*.png" and make your output from all different images.

Answer (score 2):

This should be the Unix equivalent of GeeMack's solution for Imagemagick

```
COLS=5

magick tile-*.png \
   -background none \
   -gravity center \
   -extent "%wx%w" \
   +gravity \
   +append \
   +repage \
   -crop "%[fx:$COLS*h]x%h" \
   -splice "%[fx:(t%2)*h/2]x0" \
   -set page "+0+%[fx:t*h*0.866]" \
   -layers merge +repage \
      result.png
```

Comment: The "-extent" operation in this command should use "%hx%h" instead of "%wx%w". I've corrected that in my example command. Might be helpful if you'd correct it here. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for adapting GeeMack's code to Unix. I work on a mac, and I definitely needed that! As I mention, due to the shape of my images I had to change ```%wx%w``` into ```%hx%h```. Also, I had to "clone" the images I needed repeating. Finally, I got the following complaint ```magick: profile 'icc': 'RGB ': RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG `result.png' @ warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1526.``` which I "solved" by adding the option ```-define png:color-type=6```. Don't know if this is the best "solution", though.

Comment: @GeeMack thanks for the pointer about the height. I've seen it only now, and I'm kind of proud I figured that out myself :) . Again thanks a lot for your detailed reply. I only needed the last bit, but I'm sure your "preliminary" codes will surely come in handy for other projects. Now that I think about it, it seems to me that the ```-duplicate``` option you use in your first code is what I need to "clone" the repeated badges!

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a way to achieve what I want. I'm not sure it's the best way, though.

So, inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50876200/run-convert-from-imagemagick-script-file), I wrote a script `hexScript` like this

```
#!/path/to/magick -script
-define png:color-type=6
( MMderivate.png -repage +0+0 )
( MMderivate.png -repage +150+0 )
( MMderivate.png -repage +300+0 )
( MMsimboli.png -repage +75+130 )
( MMsimboli.png -repage +225+130 )
( MMpercentuali.png -repage +375+130 )
-layers merge -write out.png
```

which i can run with `magick -script hexScript`. The output is pretty much what I'm looking for (see below).

Of course, in my case the number of lines like `( file.png -repage +X+Y )` is going to be way larger than six, but I think imagemagick can handle that (the OP in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50876200/run-convert-from-imagemagick-script-file) talks about thousands of images).

Now I just have to write a code that automatically produces the script I need, based on the information of how many badges of each kind I need.

Any insight for improving this approach is welcome.

Thanks a lot

Francesco

[image: result]